# What is the difference between ssh proxycommand -W, nc, exec nc

Tags: ssh

I have seen a few blogs about .ssh/config and `proxycommand`

now what is the difference between the next commands

`ProxyCommand ssh proxyserver -W [%h]:%p`

`ProxyCommand ssh proxyserver nc -q0 %h %p 2> /dev/null`

`ProxyCommand ssh proxyserver exec nc -q0 %h %p 2> /dev/null`

Some of these commands work on some machines, and don't work on others.

Comment: "... don't work on others" is rather vacuous...

Comment: The old `nc` version doesn't allow using different usernames for the bastion and target server. Also, I recently learned that ssh 7.3 and newer introduced a `ProxyJump` parameter which is a more user-friendly option to the ones you mentioned.

Comment: for interested: ssh supports jump option -J: `ssh -J firewall.example.org:22 server2.example.org` . see more at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Here's how I understand it:

---

1. `ProxyCommand ssh proxyserver -W [%h]:%p`

   - The `-W` option is built into new(er) versions of OpenSSH, so this will only work on machines that have the minimum version (5.4, unless your distro back-ported any features; e.g., RHEL6 OpenSSH 5.3p1 includes this feature). Per the release notes: http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.4

     > Added a 'netcat mode' to ssh(1): "ssh -W host:port ..." This connects stdio on the client to a single port forward on the server. This allows, for example, using ssh as a ProxyCommand to route connections via intermediate servers.
2. `ProxyCommand ssh proxyserver nc -q0 %h %p 2> /dev/null`

   - Before the `-W` option was available, we used the `nc` (or netcat) utility. `nc` allows you to forward TCP & UDP packets to specified (alternate) locations and essentially behaves the same as `ssh -W` (as `ssh -W` was modeled after `nc`). In order for this variation to work the intermediate host(s) require(s) that `nc` be installed and the option `AllowTcpForwarding` must be enabled in the host's sshd_config (default: yes). The option `-q0` to `nc` is (supposed to be) for quieting errors, but I can't find which version this was introduced. (Note: `2> /dev/null` is probably to quite `ssh` errors, but one can use `ssh -q` instead.)
3. `ProxyCommand ssh proxyserver exec nc -q0 %h %p 2> /dev/null`

   - This is very much the same as the second variation, except you're calling the shell's built-in function `exec`. I'm not sure, but I believe there is no difference between including or excluding `exec` from the `ProxyCommand`; this variation should function everywhere the variation above does. For example, the Bash manual says something like this:

     > exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
     >
     > If  command  is  specified,  it replaces the shell.  No new process is created.  The arguments
     >   become the arguments to command.  If the -l option is supplied, the shell places a dash at the
     >   beginning  of  the  zeroth  argument  passed  to command.  This is what login(1) does.  The -c
     >   option causes command to be executed with an empty environment.  If -a is supplied, the  shell
     >   passes name as the zeroth argument to the executed command.  If command cannot be executed for
     >   some reason, a non-interactive shell exits, unless the shell option execfail  is  enabled,  in
     >   which  case  it  returns  failure.  An interactive shell returns failure if the file cannot be
     >   executed.  If command is not specified, any redirections take effect in the current shell, and
     >   the return status is 0.  If there is a redirection error, the return status is 1.

Comment: I have missed your comment for a while, and thanks for the explenation. But there is a difference betwen 2. and 3. because they don't both always work on some machines at the same time (one works while the other doesn't). Difference between -W and nc was expected but I have no idea why I see differences between "exec nc" and just "nc".

Comment: `exec` ends the shell and replaces it with the `nc` process, rather than running `nc` in a sub-process. It is good practice, because the shell isn't needed at that point and the process tree is neater without an unnecessary shell in the chain, but it shouldn't affect whether server-jumping works or not. In some cases, like when running services in a supervisor, it is essential for signaling to work properly, but here that is not a factor.

Comment: Now there is also the option "ProxyJump" which simplifies it even more!