# SSH interception - Linux

Tags: linux, ssh

Really hoping someone here can point me in the right direction,

Expected result: SSH successfully into a remote device.

Challenge/Back story: 
We have devices out in remote places around the country, 
These devices do not have a fixed public IP address
(Using GSM as its internet breakout)
These devices are able to SSH and break out.

My thought, with regards to maintaining these devices is to (if possible) use a server in the cloud as a middle man, have these devices create some sort of a reverse tunnel to our middleman server then have us as admins intercept it or something to that effect.

Again to summarize, Device cannot be ssh'd into directly, but can breakout. 
Aim to be able to hit their terminal from the office.

have been looking at mitmssh but not coming right on that front.

Server A (no fixed address, cannot SSH into it directly but has breakout)

Server B (standard server which can be used as a middle man

Server C (Us admins)

Tried something along the lines of "ssh user@serverA -R serverB:12345:ServerA:22"

Which creates the tunnel, but struggling with grabbing hold of that SSH connection.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question in any way, shape or form, but a networking one. As such, and given that it's about ssh, I'd suggest you ask this at https://unix.stackexchange.com, https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux# or https://serverfault.com/questions

Comment: Thanks for the links, Was unclear on it being programming specific, My apologies

Comment: For the reference: they CAN be sshed into directly (if you choose to make it so), you just don't know their IP. What I do to get into my machine is to make it "call home", pushing it's current IP every five minutes to an IP I can always access. I do this via cating and a forced command on the far end.

Comment: No worries. It's a good question. ;) Just the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks a mil,
Found their public IP changes each time it makes a connection through GSM, must have something to do with the Mobile operator. 
Will try your suggestion though, thanks again

Comment: Well, that's no problem - as long as they can determine what their public ip is; mine changes on no regular pattern, sometimes it's stable for weeks, sometimes it changes twice a day .. :D

Answer (score 0):

I think I regularly use something very similar.  My target machine connects to the machine with a stable address with:

```
ssh midpoint -R 2022:localhost:22
```

my `~/.ssh/config` file knows the real `HostName`.  My `config` file on my work machine defines a `ProxyCommand` option to use this tunnelled TCP connection.  like:

```
Host target
  ProxyCommand ssh -q midpoint nc localhost 2022
```

the reason for using netcat was to get `ssh-agent` behaving.

I've just been searching around and it seems OpenSSH now has specific handling for this (`-W` command line option, and `JumpHost` in the config file).  E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29176698/1358308